# Mac OS X: Interrupt auto-login

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, login

I have several accounts on my Mac (OS X 10.6.4). One of them is setup so it is logged in automatically on system startup. So if I just boot up the machine I end up in this account.

Is there a way to interrupt the auto-login process (by pressing a certain key-combination during boot?) so I end up in the login-screen instead?

Comment: This may not be possible, as there is no command for this listed at Apple's own rather extensive list of keyboard shortcuts: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343

Answer (score 3):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> at the precise time: To get the login window, you just have hold down that key when it transitions from the grey Apple logo to the light blue screen until the login window appears.

Tested fine in 10.6.4

PS: I do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> but @Chealion test it with just press <kbd>shift</kbd> and edit this answer.

Comment: On MacOS Monterey, the above procedure worked fine and saved my day. I was loggin in remotely using screen sharing and had to press Shift + Option + Cmd simultaneously. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on a 10.6.8 MBP:
Once the gray Apple logo appears, hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and keep holding it until the gray screen changes to blue.. *mind the timing though: hit to early and you'll start in verbose mode, release to early, and it doen't work.*

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off auto-login in the Security panel in System Preferences. When you add a second account to your machine is used to ask you if you would like to turn this option off.

Comment: This is not what i want. I want to have auto-login on _unless_ i press a certain key during machine startup.